# Connect to (open) LDAP with javascript or jQuery and no Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, ldap, openldap

I have a pure js/html POC web application and I am trying to authenticate users through ldap. I can't seem to find any info on how to do this, is this even possible?.

The only answers I see come around by using node.js like [ldapjs.org](http://ldapjs.org/) and [ldapauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapauth) but I was trying to avoid node.js since I'm not comfortable with and for time limitations.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't initiate a LDAP connection from javascript in a browser without using third party application/extension/...

LDAP is a protocol such as http, and you have to use this protocol to authenticate against a directory.

There are different solutions though :

- Use basic authentication which uses a LDAP directory as the users backend
- Expose an api which will make the authentications (available in mostly every language : php, nodejs, python, perl, etc.)
- Use a third party product which will handle that for you ([LemonLdap::NG](https://lemonldap-ng.org/welcome/) for example, which will have a portal, and your application will be accessible through the LL::NG proxy)
- etc.